# zend query maximum field length

Tags: zend-framework, field, max

Im trying to insert a log record in my log table. But somehow when the field value lenght exceeds 199 chars, my apache restarts and my browsers says net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
I'm using the Zend Framework, so I insert my record with the following lines of code:

```
    $db = Global_Db_Connection::getInstance();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO log_table (log) VALUES ('ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd')";
    $db->query($sql);
```

If i dont use the framework, using:

```
    mysql_query($sql);
```

Then i dont have any problems.

Anyone can tell me how to fix this limit in Zend?

Tried this on FreeBSD same problem. I also found out that when trying to insert it into a table that does not exist, it returns the same error. Only after shortening the value it gives the error that the table does not exist.

Comment: Did you try using PDO natively?

Comment: I dont exactly understand what you mean, but i have database.adapter         = pdo_mysql in my ini file

Comment: Is Apache/PHP running on Windows?

Comment: @fr0sty, Zend_db uses PDO internaly, so I advise you to try with PDO directly, to see if it is a limitation of Zend_Db, PDO, or PHP itself.
Another question, can you check your log to see what error is throwed? I'm wondering if you are trying ton insert a too long value in a mysql column (let's say a VARCHAR(200));

Comment: Running on Windows. When using mysql_connect, mysql_select_db and mysql_query to execute the query i dont have any problems. So it seems like a limitation in Zend to me. Apache throws the error "[Wed Jul 11 09:22:21 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting." No errors in my mysql log.

Comment: Tried it on FreeBSD but same problem..

Answer (score 0):

May be late to answer, but I have the soultion. Two solution for zend I found:

1. `$db->getConnection()->query($sql); // use getConnection()`
2. `$db->exec($sql);`

This issue is because of memory stack size. On linux the stack grows as needed, but on Windows & Mac this issue gets bubbled because of the stack size. For this there a ticket raised in php.net([here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49729)) Have a look. Enjoy!!!